# Multiprocessing with Python and tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, multiprocessing

This seems trivial but I just cannot explain it ...

I have the following, working tkinter code sim.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import random
import time

class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title="Device", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        print("CHILD.GUI: Entered __init__")
        self.title(title)
        tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", command=self.on_quit).pack(side="top", padx=30, pady=30)
        """ <RUN> """
        self.mainloop()

    def on_quit(self):
        print("Quitting ...")
        self.destroy()

def main():
    root = MainApp()

def my_dev( kill_queue, child_conn):
    print ("CHILD: Entered device function ...")
    root = MainApp()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# EOF sim.py
```

But when I try to execute it as a child from main program main.py:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import sys
import time
import signal
import tkinter as tk
import sim

nproc = 1
result = 0
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print ('\nCaught interrupt, cleaning up...')
    print (process.terminate())
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kill_queue = mp.Queue()
    parent_connection, child_connection = mp.Pipe()
    process = mp.Process(target=sim.my_dev, args=(kill_queue,child_connection,))
    process.start()
    print("Spawning process with PID:{}".format(process.pid) )
    # finite number of runs ...
    for dummy in range(100):
        while parent_connection.poll():
            result = parent_connection.recv()
        print("Data: {:8.2f}".format(result), end="")
        print("\r", end="")
        time.sleep(.1)
    # Finishing up ... sending a kill signal
    print("\n\n")
    kill_queue.put(True)
    process.join()

    print ('Main thread done.')
```

I get nothing.  It prints "CHILD: Entered device function" and that's it.  "CHILD:GUI" does NOT print.  No error.  I can see the CHILD process with

```
ps ax
```

and it terminates when the main program finishes.

Note, that I have deleted PIPE part in the child ... actually that part worked if I get rid of GUI.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Radek

EDIT: fixed (hopefully) the parent comment.  Also fixed the window title.  It still does not run tho.  Trying the flush ...

EDIT: flush after print in my_dev and after root = MainApp() gave nothing ...

EDIT: flush did something (handy little thing).  I added tkinter into the main.py (just tk.Tk() to initialize).  Suddenly, the code entered into the MainApp (displayed: CHILD.GUI: Entered **init**) and gave an error:

2020-06-09 01:15:45.982 python[50273:22418845] Could not retrieve fonts from the server! Registering system fonts locally...

Btw, 50273 is a correct PID of the spawned process.

I have also added my GUI function directly to main.py ... same error.  The error seems to be related to spawning new process ... I had no luck finding any solution ... suggestions?  R>

Comment: I checked again: for some reason the CHILD process is a zombie (Z+ in ps ax).  I still do not get it. R>

Comment: The console output in the child process may be cached, try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print statement.  BTW, `tk.Tk()` does not have parent, so `parent` argument in `MainApp.__init__()` should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

So there is an answer ... sort of.

The code works perfectly on Debian Linux (Raspbian to be precise).

I still do get the error message on my Mac regarding missing fonts:
`2020-06-09 01:15:45.982 python[50273:22418845] Could not retrieve fonts from the server! Registering system fonts locally...` As I mentioned above it only appeared in the system flush after including `tk.Tk()` in the main program.

Just for completeness:  I have `pyenv` installed on my Mac using home-brew.  All python3 packages are installed via pip.  Everything else seems to be working as expected.  The tkinter code above runs fine when executed as a main program.  Anytime it is called through multiprocessing, it won't work.

Ultimately, I need the program to run on Linux; I use my Mac for coding non-hardware parts (like GUI).  It would be nice to have this actually working correctly on Mac as well.

Suggestions?

Peace!
Radek